# NetSuite Custom Field Reference

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom record, which of course has custom fields, and I'm creating a Workflow for this record. It's a simple Workflow that simply creates a new Employee Record if this custom record is set to a certain status. I have all of this working, but I want to set certain fields in the Employee Record to particular values base on the field values of the custom record.

For example, the custom record has two fields: First Name (ID: custrecord29) and Last Name (ID: custrecord30). I simply want to set the Email field for the Employee record to the concatenation of their first name and last name. I have a formula to do this (which doesn't work hence my post):

CONCAT({custrecord29},{custrecord30}, "@mydomain.com")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the double pipe - `||` - to concat instead of the concat function. Also note, you should use single quotes with netsuite server side strings. Try the following formula:

```
{custrecord29}||{custrecord30}||'@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: I didn't try the || but I did use the single quotes which worked for me. I had to use to CONCATs to make it work.

Comment: I confirmed the double pipe || works in a NetSuite saved search using the Formula Text field.  Up until now I have been using nested CONCAT formulas which are difficult to follow.  Thanks TMann!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('', {custrecord29}), CONCAT('', {custrecord30})), "@mydomain.com")
```

I haven't tested it but that should give you an idea.